# Is the product of two uniformly convergent sequence of functions uniformly convergent?

Tags: analysis, sequence-of-function

I am doing the exercise V.1.7 of Amann and Escher's *Analysis*. In the exercise I am required to prove that the product of two uniformly convergent sequence of functions is uniformly convergent if just one of them is bounded. But I found a counter example:
$$f_n=1/n,\quad g_n=x+1/n,\quad x\in \mathbb R$$
They are both uniformly convergent and $f_n$ is bounded but the product doesn't. Is there a mistake in the exercise or there are more conditions needed?

Comment: Due to $|f_n(x)g_n(x) - f(x)g(x)| \leq |f_n(x)||g_n(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)||f_n(x) - f(x)|$ we would want both $f_n$ and $g_n$ to be bounded to guarantee $f_ng_n$ converges uniformly.